# How to add template in template directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 directives with different templates, but in every template I have a table which is almost the same every time, its just with different array. How can I make that that table to be in link or something like that and only to give her what array?

For example, I have that in directive template and the table without checkbox . In every template I have different thing like here I have checkbox in other I have button and.

```
<table ng-show="myprops.List.length>0" class="table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAll()" ng-model = "isAllSelected" ></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="node in myprops.List">
                        <th>{{node.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>
                        <th>{{node.endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>
                        <th>{{node.workInHours }}</th>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="onClick()" ng-model="node.selected" ></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button ng-show="myprops.List.length>0"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteItems()">Remove</button>
```

Only this is the same with the different array with the same props ..

```
<tr>
                            <th>Start Date</th>
                            <th>End Date</th>
                            <th>Hours</th>
...
 </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="node in myprops.List">
                            <th>{{node.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>
                            <th>{{node.endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>
                            <th>{{node.workInHours }}</th>
```

Comment: Depends on how different the array is. If one has more properties or different ones than the other, you could do the way you do now.

Comment: I try to add directive in that html template and it didnt work , array is with the same properties but its a different array

Comment: So you tried to make the table a directive and put it into the 3 directive templates? What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I edit it look what is the same...

Comment: I think you could include the whole table. And why don't you include the checkboxes?

Comment: cuz in the other template i dont have checkbox their i have buttons and on third template i dont have anything

Comment: I have this problems all the time whether to make some code reusable or not. If I were you I would do the same way you do now. Or you could wait if someone has a answer on how to easily and rationally do it.